# Extending type aliases in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am dealing with different units, i.e. `distance`, `altitude`, `speed`, `volume`, etc.

My goal is to have an elegant, unique way to format them in the app, like for example calling `myValue.formatted`:

```
let mySpeed: Speed = 180
println(mySpeed.formatted) // 5.0 km/h

let myAltitude: Altitude = 4000
println(myAltitude.formatted) // 4000 m
```

I thought this was a good case for using type aliases.

```
typealias Distance = Float
typealias Altitude = Float
typealias Speed = Float
```

For the `formatted` property, I tried with an `extension` of the type `Float`:

```
extension Float {
    var formatted: String {
        get {
            switch self {
            case is Altitude:
                return "\(self) m"
            case is Speed:
                return "\(self * 3.6) km/h"
            default:
                return "\(self)"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But the compiler says that my *`case` blocks are always `true`*.

Then i tried to extend the single type:

```
extension Speed {
  var formatted: String {
    return "\(self * 3.6) km/h"
  }
}
extension Altitude {
  var formatted: String {
    return "\(self) m"
  }
}
```

the compiler now clearly states *Invalid redeclaration of 'formatted'*

OK, it's clear now how type aliases work. But how would I get my `.formatted` property for different types of Floats in swift?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`typealias` just change or rename the type. It does not create another user type for you. You are actually extending `Float` for `Speed`, `Altitude` again.

You can pass `180` to your custom struct by conforming `Literals` types.

```
let mySpeed: Speed = 180
```

`FloatLiteralConvertible` and `IntegerLiteralConvertible` will give you same functionality you want and you can directly assign values to your custom `struct types` as you assign to `Float`

```
struct Speed: FloatLiteralConvertible,IntegerLiteralConvertible {

    var distance:Float
    init(floatLiteral value: Float) {
        distance = value
    }

    init(integerLiteral value: Int){
        distance = Float(value)
    }

    var formatted: String {
        return "\(distance * 3.6) km/h"
    }
}

let mySpeed: Speed = 180.0
println(mySpeed.formatted) // 5.0 km/h
```

Comment: This is very interesting indeed. It is a bit disappointing I can't cast a `floatVar as Speed`, i.e. using the `as` keyword. The type alias was elegant this way.

Comment: @crumblenaut you are right.Speed is now not `Float`.It is user defined custom type.You can `format` `Float` with one function with one kind.If you really want to do that use `formatSpeed`,formatDistance in extensions.

Answer (score 1):

`Distance`, `Altitude`, and `Speed` is always the same type - `Float` and share the same `formatted` property. This is how compiler sees your code:

```
extension Float {
    var formatted: String {
        get {
            switch self {
            case is Float:
                return "\(self) m"
            case is Float:
                return "\(self * 3.6) km/h"
            default:
                return "\(self)"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I guess you need to create small wrappers for your functionality:

```
struct Distance {
    var value: Float
    var formatted: String {
        return "\(value) m"
    }

    init(_ value: Float) {
        self.value = value
    }
}

let myDistance = Distance(123)
myDistance.formatted
```

Comment: Thank you for the insight. Sadly doing this way I can't write: `let mySpeed: Speed = 30`. I think I'll go with another "formatting" solution.

Comment: You can do `let mySpeed = Speed(30.0)` with this approach.

Comment: @crumblenaut look at this [article](http://nshipster.com/swift-literal-convertible/) to know how to implement literal assignment